# How can we avoid losing writes when using lightweight transactions (CAS) in Cassandra?

Tags: concurrency, transactions, cassandra, compare-and-swap, optimistic-concurrency

I'm doing some tests on Cassandra, to see if we could use it for a scalable key-value store which supports optimistic concurrency.

Since a key-value store only needs a single table and each item is accessed by key, it seems that [lightweight transactions](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0) could easily provide the technical foundation for our problem.

However, when running [a test which does a number of concurrent updates](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4c83f2962b57fce4c3df) (and retries as long as concurrency is detected), **we see that we lose writes**.

The test creates a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE objects (key text, version int, PRIMARY KEY(key));
```

And inserts a number of keys using:

```sql
INSERT INTO objects (key, version) VALUES (?, 0) IF NOT EXISTS;
```

The version of these items is then incremented a number of times using a CAS operation:

```sql
-- client retrieves the current version
SELECT version FROM objects WHERE key = ?;

-- and updates the item using the retrieved version as version check
UPDATE objects SET version = ? WHERE key = ? IF version = ?;
```

The client code actually looks like this for the update:

```cs
private async Task<bool> CompareAndSet(string key, int currrentCount, PreparedStatement updateStatement)
{
    // increment the version
    IStatement statement = updateStatement.Bind(currrentCount + 1, key, currrentCount);

    // execute the statement
    RowSet result = await Session.ExecuteAsync(statement);

    // check the result
    Row row = result.GetRows().SingleOrDefault();

    if (row == null)
        throw new Exception("No row in update result.");

    // check if the CAS operation was applied or not
    return row.GetValue<bool>("[applied]");
}
```

As you can see, the CAS operation could not have been applied because of concurrency. So, this operation is retried until it succeeds. Write timeout exceptions are also handled. [The rationale behind handling the write timeout exceptions is explained here.](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201312.mbox/%3CCAHqkQ+a=KnPUYWH9G+N6NGeF3seUOCE-6-e5HzPA4gUftqioHw@mail.gmail.com%3E)

```cs
private async Task Update(string key, PreparedStatement selectStatement, PreparedStatement updateStatement)
{
    bool done = false;

    // try update (increase version) until it succeeds
    while (!done)
    {
        // get current version                
        TestItem item = null;

        while (item == null)
            item = await GetItem(key, selectStatement);

        try
        {
            // update version using lightweight transaction 
            done = await CompareAndSet(key, item.Version, updateStatement);

            // lightweight transaction (CAS) failed, because compare failed --> simply not updated
            if (!done)
                Interlocked.Increment(ref abortedUpdates);
        }
        catch (WriteTimeoutException wte)
        {
            // partial write timeout (some have been updated, so all must be eventually updated, because it is a CAS operation)
            if (wte.ReceivedAcknowledgements > 0)
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref partialWriteTimeouts);
                done = true;
            }
            else
                // complete write timeout --> unsure about this one...
                Interlocked.Increment(ref totalWriteTimeouts);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output for a test which uses 100 items and updates each item 10 times:

```
Running test with 100 items and 10 updates per item.

Number of updates: 1000
Number of aborted updates due to concurrency: 3485
Number of total write timeouts: 18
Number of partial write timeouts: 162

LOST WRITES: 94 (or 9,40%)

Results: 

Updates | Item count
     10 |         35
      9 |         43
      8 |         17
      7 |          3
      6 |          2

Xunit.Sdk.EqualExceptionAssert.Equal() Failure
Expected: 0
Actual:   94
```

As you can see, this is a highly concurrent test (see the number of aborted operations where the update has to be retried). **But, the bad news is that we are losing writes.** The client thinks 1000 updates should have been performed, but 94 writes were lost in this case.

The number of lost writes is in the order of magnitude of the number of write timeouts. So, they seem to be linked. The question is:

- do we need to deal with timeout exceptions in a better way?
- is there a way to avoid lost writes when doing CAS operations on Cassandra?

Comment: This looks like an excellent JIRA ticket - Cassandra version, JVM used, and DEBUG system.log might also be helpful :) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA

Comment: Ok, first we're going to test using the latest Cassandra version (we were using 2.0.9 until now).

Comment: The problem is the same using version 2.1.2.

Comment: I create a JIRA ticket for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8446

Answer (score 3):

The WriteTimeoutException indicates that Cassandra was not able to perform the operation in time. With your test you put Cassandra under heavy load and any operation may fail with a timeout exception. So what you need to do is redo your operation and recover from the problem by repeated attempt. It is similar to an SQLTimeoutException. You need to defend against that also.

Comment: There's no way to tell from the WriteTimeoutException whether the LWT will actually succeed or not? Is this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9328 ?

Comment: That problem is a different thing and something that should stop you from using Cassandra if the success of your firm is based on data integrity and a reason some still use relational databases in certain circumstances even if those do not scale.

This bug even invalidates my advice. You should not redo the transaction in any case then.

Comment: So basically yes, in terms of timeout, you will never know. Before this bug thing, the chances were quite slim that a timeout occures but the call succeeded. The window was by the timeout was hit but there were outstanding ACK. That is why we used to have all shards local and the timeout reasonable high. So basically there was no chance for a timeout other than contention and broken system and if you retry it you will find out.

Comment: The problem is also if you have a write timeout it can be that other replicas catch up with those already accepting the value. Repeatingly writing the value is like seeding it to as much shards as required.

This is why we use Cassandra for media data and logs but not for data we need to trust for 100% correctness.

Comment: Can you perform a SERIAL read to find out what actually happened, or is LWT essentially broken?

Comment: I might not be the right person to answer this. I usually let the developers answer the question. The problem for me is that I do not know what cassandra is doing when a transaction timed out. Does it compensate (I do not think so) or does it let the system run as it is since shards usually catch up if they notice a version differs from those of other replicas (which is what I expect).

Comment: Also I do not think a serial read gets you anything in this regard. I do not know how the driver and system should answer... maybe it forces other shards to update their values somehow. Again this is something only the source code and the devs can tell you. For that reasons I advise to use Cassandra only for data that must only be quasi correct (semi correct). If you need full correctness Cassandra is not the correct choice.

Comment: Apparently the answer is yes: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9328?focusedCommentId=15101847&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15101847

Comment: The question is if this is true for non-serial writes. Remember serial is dead as in slow for most of the things... . (but I am no expert and maybe something also has changed). I am currently not working with Cassandra so I might have missed the changes being applied for the last year.

Comment: The point about Timeout exceptions is that, in all databases and in all systems, there are cases which are "InDoubt", which makes this answer good and correct. Not a bug, not anything that can be changed architecturally. Imagine the case where you send an update. The database does the work and queues the response. While the response is waiting in the outbound TCP queue, the server crashes. Since it's a good database that has commit logic, the write has been applied, but the alternate case ( database never received the write from TCP ) results in the same externally visible error.